# In fluent-nhibernate can you intercept a select query to perform additional filtering based on a subclass

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I've searched through various questions on this site, and they came close to answering what I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to piece everything together to get it to work. Basically what I had is something along these lines:

```
class test: subclass
{
  int happyInt;
  //Other stuff goes here, doesn't really matter for this example.
}

class test2: subclass
{
  string happyString;
  //Other stuff goes here, doesn't really matter for this example.
}

class subclass
{
  int intIWantToFilterby;
}
```

I have everything mapped and I can get data in and out of the DB without issue, and I even have interceptors that are working, but basically what I want is everytime a select is performed for test or test2 as part of the select I want it to check to see if intIWantToFilterby is equal to some value. I realize I can do this manually, but I have a large number of classes that all inherit from subclass and I don't want to have to write the exact same logic over a 100 times. So far I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but from my searching on fluent's site and the nhibernate's site as well as here I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Only test and test2 should be filtered, or all the other subclasses too? What does it mean "everytime a select is performed (...) I want it to check to see if intIWantToFilterby is equal to some value"? What do you do with the result of this check?

Comment: I don't understand your problem so I can't give you any advise.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that inherits subclass and put all your generic logic/s in there. Now create test and test2 and inherit your other general logic class.